# How do I display message from from `adb shell` (or a shell script)?

Tags: shell, command-line, user-interface

I expect it to be something like

```
adb shell am start SomethingArcane ... "Hello, world"
```

and the message box pops up on screen, saying "Hello, world".

Comment: Link: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/zenity-alternative-for-android

Answer (score 2):

### Hacky workaround: DirectFB

With DirectFB and root access, you can display the text on screen directly, without Android at all.

I've implemented a program for this: [directfbtext](https://gist.github.com/vi/07a9820c31bccfa16d1e).

```
( echo "Hello, world"; echo "FLIP"; sleep 2; echo "QUIT" ) |  /h/bin/directfbtext --dfb:fbdev=/dev/graphics/fb0  --dfb:no-vt  /system/fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf 30 120 200 255
```

Note that it is probably not that easy to get DirectFB working on Android, but I happen to have it already configured.

---

**Update** Per user request, I've created and tested a "portable" pre-built version of directfbtext. Setting up and running:

1. Unpack [directfbtext_deps.tar.gz](http://vi-server.org/pub/directfbtext_deps.tar.gz) into `/data/local/tmp/`;
2. Start `adb shell`, go root (`su`);
3. `cd /data/local/tmp/directfbtext`;
4. Create symlink from `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/` to `/data/local/tmp/directfbtext`:

   ```
   # mount -o remount,rw / /
   # mkdir /usr
   # mkdir /usr/lib
   # ln -s /data/local/tmp/directfbtext /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi
   ```
5. Ensure display is on
6. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./ld-linux.so.3 ./directfbtext --dfb:fbdev=/dev/graphics/fb0 --dfb:no-vt /system/fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf --dfb:system=fbdev 30 120 200 255`
7. Type some text, followed by a line that reads "FLIP";
8. Observe the text visible on the display;
9. Type "QUIT" to exit directfbtext;
10. Interact with the device, so it updates display and clears remaining glitches caused by DirectFB.

Comment: Maybe you can tell what need to be configured?

Comment: The main thing is probably a Debian in chroot.

Comment: Could you provide a binary? (Or instructions how to compile with NDK?)

Comment: Unfortunately static binaries are tricky to get with DirectDB. The program was build not using Android NDK and depends on Debian libraries. I'll try to hack up "semi-portable" version of it now.

Comment: @user1147688, Done. You can try testing it.

Answer (score 2):

**FBTrueType-android**

I have written a native android program [FBTrueType-android](https://github.com/mikelinux/fbtruetype-android) to print TrueType font text directly to the display on the device using ADB.

It has many features including clearing the framebuffer (display) and changing the *.ttf font used, font color, font size, x and y positions.

It also can run with Zygote (android interface) running and it can capture the framebuffer from Zygote in fullscreen.

I setup a github repository for it which you can access [here](https://github.com/mikelinux/fbtruetype-android), alternatively you can clone the repository like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mikelinux/fbtruetype-android.git
```

You will need to be setup to cross compile for ARM, the README file has full instructions on doing this.

Enjoy, and please post your feedback.

Mike